# Ubuntu 12.04 External HD Issues

Tags: windows, files, directory, clipboard, delete

I am experiencing one more problem with my Ubuntu 12.04...

I have an External HD (500GB) which is NTFS formatted. I connected this HD on my Ubuntu 12.04 and copied some files. When I connected the HD on a Windows 7 machine I could find the folders (the were visible) but I wasn't able to copy/cut/delete them. However when I opened the folders I could handle the material (mp3s) in them.

Does anybody know how can I fix this? How can I fully access and modify folders copied from Ubuntu via a Windows machine?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I really figured out what's going on! And yes, you'll laugh! You just have to take the ownership of the folders from Windows --> Right Click on the Folder --> Properties --> Security Tab --> Advanced --> Owner --> Chose your username (admin), click Apply and you're done! You can delete/cut the folder and all the files inside it! :)))

Comment: PS! If the Security Tab does not appear --> open Windows Explorer, and choose Folder Options from the Tools menu --> On the View tab, scroll to the bottom of the Advanced Settings and clear (click) the check box next to "Use Simple File Sharing --> Click OK to apply the change, and you should now have a Security tab when viewing the properties of a file or a folder on an NTFS volume.